# Generic Controller does not execute UnitOfWork method Complete()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC I created a generic Controller for CRUD operations for basic models.

I'm passing a generic repository Interface to the controller as well as unitofwork Interface. I use Ninject to inject dependency on implementation.

The repository injection works, for instance Index action works and View is displayed correctly, but when the program reaches _unitOfWork.Complete() nothing happens and DB doesn't get updated.

The generic repository and unitofwork do work in other cases when I inject them to standard non-generic controllers.

What am I doing wrong?

**GenericController.cs**

```
public class GenericController<TEntity> : Controller
    where TEntity : class

{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<TEntity> _repository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    protected GenericController(IGenericRepository<TEntity> repository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    // GET: FileTypes
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_repository.GetAll());
    }

    // GET: FileTypes/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: FileTypes/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] TEntity entity)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repository.Add(entity);
            _unitOfWork.Complete();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(entity);
    }

    // GET: FileTypes/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        var entity = _repository.GetById(id);

        if (entity == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        return View(entity);
    }

    // POST: FileTypes/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] TEntity entity)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repository.Edit(entity);
            _unitOfWork.Complete();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(entity);
    }

    // POST: FileTypes/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = RoleName.Admin + ", " + RoleName.SuperAdmin)]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            _repository.Remove(_repository.GetById(id));
            _unitOfWork.Complete();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500);
        }

    }

}
```

Example derived Controller:

**DisengagementReasonsController.cs**

```
[Authorize(Roles = RoleName.SuperAdmin)]
public class DisengagementReasonsController : GenericController<DisengagementReason>
{
    public DisengagementReasonsController(IGenericRepository<DisengagementReason> repository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        : base(repository, unitOfWork)
    {

    }
}
```

**IUnitOfWork.cs**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Complete();
}
```

**UnitOfWork.cs**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly MyAppDbContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(MyAppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }     
}
```

**Ninject.Web.Common**

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start()
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
            RegisterServices(kernel);

            kernel.Bind(x =>
            {
                x.FromThisAssembly()
                    .SelectAllClasses()
                    .BindDefaultInterface();
            });

            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
    }
}
```

**GenericRepository.cs**

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly MyAppDbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(MyAppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbSet.ToList();
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetById(object id)
    {
        return _dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Edit(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        _dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        _context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Remove(object id)
    {
        var entityToDelete = _dbSet.Find(id);
        Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Remove(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (_context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            _dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        _dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your post doesn't provide enough information to tell what's going wrong. The UoW looks ok but how is your repository class implemented? How is the DI container configured? Did you verify that the UoW and the repo instances work with the same DbContext instance?

Comment: Hi. I added NinjectWebCommon configuration and repo implementation. The UoW and the repository do work in other cases with the same DBContext (in standard controllers), but this is my first attempt at a generic controller.

Comment: @xrsnik I did not see any registration in `Ninject`.

Comment: @Win there is binding by convention. Also on debugging I can see that both the repo and uow have values that I'd expect

Comment: Now GenericRepository and UnitOfWork don't even inject the same type of DbContext (ElmboardDbContext vs MyAppDbContext). Is this a typo?

Comment: @Adam Simon That was a typo in question but I am now looking at your first comment and I need to check if the UoW and repo work with the same context instance. I'll let you know.

Comment: Ok, repo looks good, too. Chances are that the problem lies in the DI configuration. How are the lifetimes of the individual components configured (DbContext, UoW, generic repo, controller)?

Comment: @Adam Simon The instance of context was different for repo and uow. Thanks so much :) Please answer and I'll accept. I introduced a property for generic repos in uow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the symptoms the most likely cause of the problem is that not the same instance of *DbContext* gets injected in the UoW and the repository class (probably due to some DI misconfiguration). After some discussion in the comments it turned out, I made a lucky hit. :)

However, as a side note, I'd point out that EF's DbContext implements UoW and repository in itself. In most cases implementing these patterns over EF is just an unnecessary overcomplication, an abstraction of an abstraction. I don't recommend this without a good reason.